# MySQL запрос на выборку данных

Tags: php, mysql

Как вытащить 50 гонщиков из бд с победами от большего к меньшему

Comment: [SQL на w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите структуру БД.

Answer (score 4):

```
select `gonshchik` from `bd_gonshchiki` order by `pobedy` desc limit 50
```

[[@xEdelweiss](/users/7017/xedelweiss)](/users/7017/xedelweiss) дело говорит

Comment: сделал но почему то по разному выводит

Comment: . 

   $top_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `turnir` WHERE (`id` != '".$winner['id']."' AND `uid` != '1' ORDER BY `win` DESC LIMIT 51");
    $top = mysql_fetch_array($top_query);

Comment: во-первых, fetch_array вам придется вызвать 51 раз, каждый раз записывая в новую переменную или выводя на экран или еще как-то обрабатывая, так как mysql_fetch_array достает только ОДИН ряд из всей выборки.
во-вторых, не закрыта скобка у where.
в-третьих, не закрыта скобка у mysql_query

Comment: скобками все норм ошибки не выдает и не выводит одного 51 раз все работает тока как бы ORDER BY DESC LIMIT не работает (

Comment: @anonymous_911_, нет, не всё нормально со скобками. Исправьте это.